# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) issue windows to linux

Tags: c++, dump, coredump, fault

I have been using Visual Studio on Windows to program and my code works fine, but when running it on Ubuntu I get a

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

issue and I don't know what is causing it. I have no idea where in the code the issue would be, so I pasted all of it.

```
#include "Person.h"
#include "Grade.h"

using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::stringstream;
using std::fixed;
using std::setprecision;
using std::setfill;

unsigned z = 0;
unsigned y = 0;

void firstInput(vector<Person>& peoples, char *argv[])
{
int x = 0;
string idy, namey, addressy, phoney, s;

ifstream one;
one.open(argv[1]);

while (getline(one, s))
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        idy = s;
    }

    if (x == 1)
    {
        namey = s;
    }

    if (x == 2)
    {
        addressy = s;
    }

    if (x == 3)
    {
        phoney = s;
        Person *f1 = new Person(idy, namey, addressy, phoney);
        peoples.push_back(*f1);
        x = -1;
    }

    x++;

}

one.close();
}

void secondInput(vector<Grade>& gradies, char *argv[])
{
int b;
string z, idy2, gradey, classy;

ifstream two;
two.open(argv[2]);

b = 0;

while (getline(two, z))
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        classy = z;
    }

    if (b == 1)
    {
        idy2 = z;
    }

    if (b == 2)
    {
        gradey = z;
        Grade *g1 = new Grade(classy, idy2, gradey);
        gradies.push_back(*g1);
        b = -1;
    }
    b++;
}

two.close();
}

double scoreConverter(string lettergrade)
{
double converted = 0.0;

if (lettergrade.substr(0,1) == "A")
{
    converted += 4;
}

if (lettergrade.substr(0,1) == "B")
{
    converted  += 3;
}

if (lettergrade.substr(0,1) == "C")
{
    converted += 2;
}

if (lettergrade.substr(0,1) == "D")
{
    converted += 1;;
}

if (lettergrade.size() > 1)
{
    if (lettergrade.substr(1,2) == "-")
    {
        converted -= 0.3;
    }
    if (lettergrade.substr(1,2) == "+")
    {
        converted += 0.4;
    }
}
return converted;
}

void computeGPA(vector<Grade>& s, vector<Person>& p, string IDnum)
{
int count = 0;
y = 0;
double gpa = 0;

    for (string x = IDnum; y < s.size(); y++)
    {
        if (x == s.at(y).getIDs())
        {
        gpa += scoreConverter(s.at(y).getScore());
        count++;
        }
    }   
        if (gpa > 0)
        {
        gpa = gpa / count;
        }
        cout << IDnum << "    ";
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setfill('0') << gpa << "    ";

    for (unsigned x = 0; x < p.size(); x++)
    {
        if (IDnum == p.at(x).getID())
        {
            cout << p.at(x).getName() << endl;
            x = 1000;
        }
    }

    z = y;
}

void thirdInput(vector<Grade>& gradies, vector<Person>& persons, char *argv[])
{
string querying;

ifstream three;
three.open(argv[3]);


while(getline(three, querying))
{
for (unsigned x = 0; x < persons.size(); x++)
{
    if (querying == persons.at(x).getID())
    {
        computeGPA(gradies, persons, persons.at(x).getID());
        x = 1000;
    }
}
}
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

ofstream outputit;
outputit.open(argv[4]);

std::ofstream out(argv[4]);
std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());

vector<Person> people;
vector<Grade> grades;

firstInput(people, argv);

std::sort(people.begin(), people.end());

    for (unsigned x = 0; x < people.size(); x++)
    {
        cout << people.at(x).getName() << endl;
        cout << people.at(x).getID() << endl;
        cout << people.at(x).getPhone() << endl;
        cout << people.at(x).getAddress() << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

secondInput(grades, argv);

std::sort(grades.begin(), grades.end());

for (unsigned x = 0; x < grades.size(); x++)
{
    cout << grades.at(x).getIDs() << "    ";
    cout << grades.at(x).getScore() << "    ";
    cout << grades.at(x).getClass() << endl;
}

cout << endl;

thirdInput(grades, people, argv);

outputit.close();
}
```

Comment: How are `Person` and `Grade` defined?

Comment: You can figure out where it's crashing based on what it has printed before it crashes. If it hasn't printed anything before crashing, add output statements until you get some output.

Comment: As well as 'where does it crash', it would be helpful to know what inputs you provide before it crashes.

Comment: Indenting your code is a good way to have more people willing to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to figure out where the segmentation fault occurs you can use `gdb`.

Compile your program with `-ggdb`, assuming you are using GCC.

Run the program using the following command:

```
gdb myprog myinputs.txt
```

Once inside `gdb` prompt, type `run`. Once the process segmentation faults, you should return to `gdb` prompt. From there, you can type `bt` to obtain the backtrace.

This should give you enough information to investigate your bug.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen because the memory given to the g++ compiler by default is 8192 KB of the stack, which is not the case for Windows machines. You can check the memory available with your distros by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
ulimit -s
```

ulimit is the number of open file descriptors per process. So, initialise your variables in such a way that the program doesn't utilise more than 8192 KB of memory like using `short int` in place of `int` (keeping in mind the overflow doesn't happen). Alternatively, you can set the ulimit of the stack to unlimited and compile the same code after entering the following in the terminal:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

In the place of `unlimited`, you can alternatively assign custom memory, for eg, if you want to assign 10000 KB, `ulimit -s 10000` should be written.

I hope this solves the problem.