# Segmentation fault (core dumped). Heapsort

Tags: c, linux, gcc, runtime-error

I have this heapsort program which run on Windows, but is giving segmentation fault on ubuntu 14.04.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 5000
int arr[N];
int size=N-1;
int parent(int i)
{
    return (i-1)/2;
}
 int lchild(int i)
{
     return 2*i+1;
}
int rchild(int i)
{
     return 2*i+2;
}
void maxheapify(int arr[],int i)
{
     int larg,t;
     int l=lchild(i);
     int r=rchild(i);
     if(arr[l]>arr[i] && l<=size)
         larg=l;
     else
         larg=i;
     if(arr[r]>arr[larg] && r<=size)
         larg=r;
         if(larg!=i)
         {
             t=arr[larg];
             arr[larg]=arr[i];
             arr[i]=t;
             maxheapify(arr,larg);
         }  
 }
 void buildmaxh(int arr[])
 {
     int i;
     for(i=N/2-1;i>=0;i--)
     maxheapify(arr,i);
 }
 void heapsort(int arr[])
 {
     int i,t;
     buildmaxh(arr);
     size--;
     for(i=N-1;i>0;i--,size--)
     {
         t=arr[0];
         arr[0]=arr[i];
         arr[i]=t;
         maxheapify(arr,0);
     }
}
int main()
{
     srand(time(NULL));
     int i;
     for( i=0;i<N;i++)
          arr[i]=rand()%101;
     heapsort(arr);
     printf("done\n\n");
     return 0;
 }
```

What is the source of error? How can I remove this error?

I tried debugging the code using gdb as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083699/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-issue-windows-to-linux). But I can't compile the program as described in the answer. I used command gcc myfile.c -ggdb myfile. 
Also,using command: gcc myfile.c -o myfile I compiled the program successfully, which gave me segmentation error.
What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: You should compile it with `gcc myfile.c -ggdb -o myfile` to add debug information.

Comment: `#0  0x0000000000400605 in maxheapify (arr=0x600d00, i=4997) at heap.c:22
#1  0x00000000004006c2 in maxheapify (arr=0x600d00, i=2498) at heap.c:33
#2  0x00000000004006ea in buildmaxh (arr=0x600d00) at heap.c:40
#3  0x000000000040070e in heapsort (arr=0x600d00) at heap.c:45
#4  0x00000000004007ff in main () at heap.c:61`

Comment: `l=9995` at line 22. But you have an array of size `5000`. So when doing `arr[l]>arr[i]` at line 22 you get segfault. Are you sure you need the `maxHeapify` to be recursive. You are getting an error at you double the value of `i` at line 33 and that creates a problem at line 22

Comment: @arunmoezhi The size checks in if-loops are used for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs in `maxheapify` when you check which of the children is `larg`:

```
if (arr[l]>arr[i] && l<=size) ...
```

You've got the checks the wrong way round. When you read `arr[l]`, `l` might be out of bounds, which is a segmentation violation. If you check the bounds first like this:

```
if (l<=size  && arr[l]>arr[i]) ...
```

the read access won't happen if `l` is out of bounds. (Remember that the `&&` and `||` operators short-circuit the evaluation: In `a && b`, `b` is never checked if `a` is already `false`, because there's no way the whole expression can be true.)

The same goes for the check of `arr[r]` some lines after that.

Also, please include `<stdlib.h>` and `<time.h>`; they are needed for your randomisation code.

Comment: Thanks, It solves the problem.
But this problem should have surfaced on Windows too. Why it worked on windows?
I used codeblocks to run the program on Windows.

Comment: @Potato_head: There is no guarantee that the program will crash, or give any kind of error message, if you read outside the bounds of an array. The C standard calls it "undefined behavior", and allows anything to happen. The program could stop with an error, it could silently go on and give an incorrect answer, or it could even give the correct answer. It depends on that particular system, how memory has been mapped into the address space of the process, and the content of that memory.